# Laravel passport 500 internal server error when using subdomain

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Using laravel passport on my local machine and domain http://myapp.test, I have no problem.

When I push the code to my server on my main domain https://myapp.com, again no problem.

However, I have a sudomain used for my live test (pre-production) before to push to the main domain in production. If I use https://dev.myapp.com, then I get a 500 internal server error.

Any idea how to fix it?

This is the guzzle call I'm doing:

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('https://dev.myapp.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 'client_id',
        'client_secret' => 'client_secret_key',
        'username' => 'john@example.com',
        'password' => '123456',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);

return $response;
```

If I change the url to my local or production website (changing the passport key and making sure the same user exists), it works properly.

Comment: Check your Laravel logs (storage/logs/laravel.log probably) and post the error.

Comment: `POST https://dev.myapp.com/oauth/token` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My bad. Just forgot to run that command on the server for that specific domain as specified in the documentation. This command generates the encryption keys Passport needs in order to generate access token.

```
php artisan passport:keys
```